# How to pass data between views and controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, controller

#### This is our Home Index:

```html
@model ELearning.Data.ELearningEgitimDTO
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    @if (TempData["message"] != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">@TempData["message"]</div>
    }
    <div>
        <div>
            @if (Model.EgitimTuru == 5)
            {
                <h1>Yangın Eğitimi</h1>
            }

            <table class="table table-responsive">
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%">Şirket Adı:</td>
                    <td width="80%">@Model.Name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Eğitimi Veren:</td>
                    <td>@Model.PersonelAdi</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Eğitim Tarihi:</td>
                    <td>@Model.Tarih</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table class="table table-responsive">
                <tr>
                    <td>Eğitim Konuları:</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var konu in Model.Adi)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><ul><li>@konu</li></ul></td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="text-right"><button onclick="getStartDate()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ">Eğitime Başla »</button></p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getStartDate() {
            
            $.post("/Video/GetStartDate",
                {
                    PerNr: @Model.PerNr,
                    StartDate: "",
                    EndDate: "",
                    EgitimFilesId: @Model.FileId
                });
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

#### This is Video Index:

```html
@model WebApplication3.Models.VideoLogsModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Video Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div>Eğitime başlanan zaman:</div>
    <div id="startdate"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <video controls controlslist="nodownload" id="videoPlayer" width: 100% height: auto>
            <source src="~/Video/GetVideo" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="text-right">
        <p id="button" onclick="egitimiBitir()" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg ">Eğitimi Bitir</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vid = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
        var button = document.getElementById("button");

        if (vid.played) {
            setInterval(function () { vid.pause(); }, 30000);
        }
        vid.addEventListener("ended", function() {
            button.className = "btn btn-success btn-lg "
        });

        function egitimiBitir() {

            if (vid.ended) {
                $.post("/Video/GetEndDate",
                    {
                        PerNr: @Model.PerNr,
                        StartDate= "",
                        EndDate: "",
                        EgitimFile sId: @Model.EgitimFilesId
                    });
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Video tamamlanmadan eğitimi bitiremezsiniz.."
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

#### This is our main model:

```
public class ELearningEgitimDTO
{
    public ELearningEgitimDTO() { }
    public ELearningEgitimDTO(string PerNr, int ID) 
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.PerNr = PerNr;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PerNr { get; set; }//katılımcıID
    public string Name { get; set; }//şirket adı
    public int EgitimTuru { get; set; }
    public DateTime Tarih { get; set; }//egitim tarihi
    public string PersonelAdi { get; set; } // eğitimi veren

    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string[] Adi { get; set; }
}
```

#### This is our model:

```
public class VideoLogsModel
{
    public int EgitimFilesId { get; set; }
    public int PerNr { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

}
```

#### This is our Home Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int EgitimId=4, string PerNr="2")
    {
        ELearningService service = new ELearningService();
        ELearningEgitimDTO egitim = new ELearningEgitimDTO(PerNr, EgitimId);
        return View(service.getInfo(egitim));   //eğitim bilgileri istenirken egitimId ve egitim kullanıcıdaki  eğitmenin perNr si verilmeli!!
    }
}
```

#### This is our Video Controller:

```
public class VideoController : Controller
{ 

    public ActionResult Index(VideoLogsModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    public ActionResult GetVideo()
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\cyare\Desktop\videoplayback.mp4"));
        //byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\melik.DESKTOP-LQQAB68\Desktop\videoplayback.mp4");
        //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\melik.DESKTOP-LQQAB68\Desktop\videoplayback.mp4", bytes);
        return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "video/mp4");
    }
    /* [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult GetStartEndDate(VideoLogsModel logs)
     {
         DateTime startDate = logs.StartDate; //database de uygun tabloya yazılır
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Video");
     }*/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetStartDate(VideoLogsModel model)
    {
        model.StartDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        ELearningDosyaKullaniciDTO user = new ELearningDosyaKullaniciDTO();
        user.egitimFileID = model.EgitimFilesId;
        user.egitimKullanıcı = model.PerNr;
        user.startDate = model.StartDate;
        ELearningService service = new ELearningService();
        //service.CreateLogs(user);
        //return RedirectToAction("Index","Video",model);*/
        return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetEndDate(VideoLogsModel model)
    {
        model.EndDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        ELearningDosyaKullaniciDTO user = new ELearningDosyaKullaniciDTO();
        user.egitimFileID = model.EgitimFilesId;
        user.egitimKullanıcı = model.PerNr;
        user.endDate = model.EndDate;
        ELearningService service = new ELearningService();
        service.UpdateLogs(user);
        TempData.Add("message", String.Format("Eğitiminiz Tamamlanmıştır!"));
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

My question is how can i pass the model from home index to video controller and then to video index?

Video Index doesn't run. It goes to video index but then it runs home index again.

Also it runs `egitimibitir()` function before button's onclick function.

Comment: Do you want to pass the entire model to the controller or simply some values and will this be using a button?

Comment: @JamesS When we click EgitimiBitir button, we want to pass VideoLogsModel to the Video Controller and go to Home Index Page.

Comment: Do you need to use javascript? It seems this would be easily done by a simple Html.BeginForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send an ajax request to your service. (endpoint => GetEndDate) I think you can change your code like that,

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/Video/GetEndDate",  //your reqeust url
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: JSON.stringify({
               // your data here
         }),
         success: function (data) {
               // check state of data
               // after check window.location = // redirect url
         },
         error: function (data) {
               // handle exception 
         }
 });
```

You can change your controller method to a data controller. (not an ActionResult. create  a custom result object which include your data and your success state. you can use this custom result object every ajax requests for return state and data). If an exception occurs while executing "GetEndDate" method, you need to handle exception and you need to show it to client. You send exception or your success complete response to to client(view). (you can handle your exception data in ajax error: function)